# how to map vectors with words in a text file

Tags: mapping, word2vec

I have a text file containing 100 sentences and 10 dimensional vector for each word is stored in another text file. I want to make a new text file where vectors will be printed for each word in a sentence in each matrix. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with Python and Gensim.

```
from gensim.models import word2vec

# Change this to your own path.
pathToBinVectors = '/data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'

model1 = word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(pathToBinVectors, binary=True)

print model1['resume'] -> This will print a vector of the word "resume".
```

Source: https://bitbucket.org/yunazzang/aiwiththebest_byor